# Replace some text (not all) within an element

Tags: jquery

I've got a jQuery date & time picker where I've constrained the input to either 00:00 or 12:00 so I can make it work in a kind of half day/full day way. This means it fills the box with something like:

`dd/mm/yy 12:00`

I'd like to be able to get the contents of this field and put it in a new field in the style of:

`dd/mm/yy PM`

So, can I get the `.val()` of this text field and replace *just some* of the content of it, rather than all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input value="dd/mm/yy 12:00" />

var x = $('input').val();
var y = x.split(' ');
var z = y[0] + ' ' + (y[1] >= '12:00' ? 'PM' : 'AM');
alert(z)
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/aGURT/

Answer (score 0):

You take the `.val()`, modify it, and then use `.val(newValue)` to set the new value.

To replace the time, you could use `value.replace(/[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/, 'something-else')`

Comment: I thought about regex but have used the split way. Cheers though!

Answer (score 0):

Quite dirty, but should work:

```
var date = 'dd/mm/yy 12:00';
var splitted = date.split(' ');
var result = splitted[0] + ' ' + (splitted[1] == '12:00' ? 'PM' : 'AM');
```

Answer (score 0):

When replacing the content of an element you always have to replace it all. Still, you could copy the entire element until the first blank space and then append your string..

```
var input = $('#yourid').text().split(' ');
var text = input[0];
/* process input[1] and add it to text */
$('#yourid').html(text).
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
var v = $.trim($('input').val());
var d;
if(v == '00:00')
     d = v.replace('00:00','AM'); $('input').val(d);
if(v== '12:00')
     d = v.replace('12:00','PM');$('input').val(d);
```